# Breadth first search on binary trees in OCaml using queues

Tags: tree, ocaml, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, breadth-first-search

I want to create a breadth-first search on binary trees in OCaml using queues, but I can't get it to work.

it seems like the function gets stuck when a node doesn't have any "neighbours".

```
let rec enque v l = 
    match l with
        [] -> [v]
    |   h::t -> h::(enque v t)

let rec qhd l =
    match l with
        h::[] -> h
    |   h::t -> qhd t

let deque l =
    match l with
        [] -> []
    |   h::t -> t

let notempty l = (l != [])

let rec breadthFirstHelp l =
    if notempty l
    then
        let cur = qhd l in
            match cur with
                Empty -> []
           |   (Node(Empty, node, Empty)) -> node::(breadthFirstHelp (deque l))
           |   (Node(left, node, right)) ->
               let l = enque right l in
               let l = enque left l in 
                   node::(breadthFirstHelp (deque l))
    else []
```

Here is a tree that I'm testing on.

```
[tree =
  Node
   (Node
     (Node (Empty, "A", Empty), "B",
      Node (Node (Empty, "C", Empty), "D", Empty)),
    "E", Node (Empty, "F", Node (Empty, "G", Node (Empty, "O", Empty))))]
```

With my code: `["E"; "B"; "A"; "A"; "A"]`

Expected result: `["E"; "B"; "F"; "A"; "D"; "G"; "C"; "O"]`

Answer (score 1):

There are three problems in your code:

First, your `qhd` function is not compatible with your `deque` and `enque` function. Indeed, for a not empty queue `q` and a value `any`, one would expect that adding elements at the end of the queue does not change the element at the top:

```
 qhd q = qhd (enque any q)
```

whereas with your implementation for a queue `q` such that `deque q` is not empty, you have

```
 qhd q = qhd (deque q)
```

Second, in your breadthFirstHelp function, the empty case always returns `[]` even if there are pending subtrees in `l`.

Fixing those two issues should give you the right result, there is however a last performance issue: the `enque` function is very expansive because it needs to traverse the whole queue.

A simple solution is to split the list in two

```
  type 'a queue = { top: 'a list; bottom: 'a list }
```

when the bottom list is kept in reverse order. Thus appending to the queue is a matter of appending at the top of the bottom list. Whereas poping the queue requires only to take the first element of the `top` list if it is not empty, or to refill it from the bottom list otherwise.